What is the primary function of a leaf?
The Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf) gives the usual view:
'A leaf (pl.: leaves) is a principal appendage of the stem of a vascular plant,[1] usually borne laterally above ground and specialized for photosynthesis.',
with the article on photosynthesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis) launching into an explanation of the capture and conversion of light energy into chemical energy stored as simple carbohydrates. In this view, light harvesting and energy conversion is primary.
However, the energy efficiency of photosynthesis is only about 0.1-4.3% (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency). If light energy capture and conversion is primary, why is the efficiency so low, especially since there seem to be some obvious ways to improve efficiency, such as increasing chloroplast density or recruiting different pigments to increase the number of usable frequencies of incoming light?
But photosynthesis requires water and carbon dioxide as well as energy to function. From the Wikipedia article:
$$
6~H_2O + 6~CO_2 + Energy \rightarrow C_6H_{12}O_6 + 6~O_2
$$
With water relatively abundant within the plant, the limiting factor would seem to be rate at which carbon dioxide can be extracted from air. Its concentration there is currently only about 430 ppm, and it was considerably lower in the recent past.
Could it be instead that leaves are structurally optimized mainly for carbon dioxide extraction, with light harvesting secondary, only just enough to process the resulting carbon? Is there any evidence for this?

I think that's an inclusive "and" in the first quote - to reword Usually specialized for photosynthesis and borne laterally above ground. Meaning that the specialization for photosynthesis isn't always a feature of leaves. IMO transpiration is far more important to the plant than photosynthesis

If you go to the "Typical efficiencies" section of the Wikipedia article you link, you'll find a breakdown of the inefficiencies of photosynthesis in plants, which states that only 30% of usable light does not hit chloroplasts. Therefore, even if 100% of usable light hit chloroplasts, efficiency would only be about 40% higher - which is a lot, but still leaves us in the 0.1-10% range. Chlorophyll also requires a ton of nitrogen, which is very often limiting to plant growth, so it might not be beneficial to add more chloroplasts for diminishing returns in photosynthetic efficiency.

In terms of recruiting different pigments - plants already do. Plant photosystems include a number of accessory pigments, which absorb wavelengths that chlorophyll a can't and fluoresce wavelengths that it can. Many algae have additional pigments that plants don't, which may just have happened to arise in algae but not plants.

@Eonema Not to mention the waste heat disposal from absorbing all the light and fixing the CO2 to sugars.

@Eonema I am aware that plants already use other pigments. They could presumably use even more if energy use efficiency was a big problem. The point is that extra energy would simply be wasted if there wasn't enough carbon to convert to carbohydrates

I would consider that photosynthesis as a term includes both the process of light harvesting and the process of carbohydrate anabolism from CO2. I don't see any tension in the definition that you've quoted. None of them is exhaustive and none of them is exclusive. Many leaves have minimal roles in either process and have been adapted to other purposes- for example parasitic plants that do not rely on photosynthesis! Biology is messy and that's ok.

Plants need to both capture carbon, and capture light energy to store it in carbon bonds. Since plants use CO2 as their carbon source, but can't store CO2 directly, carbon capture and photosynthesis are intimately linked. In my opinion, it doesn't really make sense to distinguish between photosynthesis or carbon capture specialization.
That said, plants have many adaptations around gas exchange. Although water is used directly in the photosynthesis reaction, the main loss of water is in the gas exchange itself. Essentially, whenever the stomata (the structures on a leaf surface that open/close to allow gas exchange) are open to accept CO2, the plant is also losing water through transpiration. Despite OP's assertion that water is abundant within a plant, most plants need to tightly control their water budget, as they will generally face water scarcity at some point in their lives.
Off the top of my head, an adaptation for increasing the gas exchange is the structure of the spongy mesophyll, which has space between the cells allowing for air exchange through the stomata. Plants have many adaptations to increase water use efficiency. Two of the primary ones are C4 and CAM photosynthesis, which separate carbon fixation from the photosynthesis reactions either physically (C4) or temporally (CAM).
Alternatively, low-light plants do have adaptations to improve light gathering, especially for light that has been filtered through leaves of an upper canopy. Plants adapted to low light may adjust the stoichiometry between photosystems I and II to better take advantage of far-red wavelengths passing through other leaves.
Because of the interplay between light, water, and carbon in photosynthesis—and the extremely varied environments that plants inhabit—I'd say that declaring that leaves are "specialized for photosynthesis" naturally encompasses a specialization for each of these resources, tailored to the habitat (and micro-habitat) of the species.
